# Why does this react component, imported with System.import, not render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-2, es6-modules

I am trying to implement dynamic code splitting with webpack 2 and react. To test I've created a component that pulls in code asynchronously:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export class Async extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { component: <div>Loading</div> }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    System.import('../../about')
      .then(component => this.setState({ component: component.About }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ component: <div>{error.message}</div> }))
  }

  render() {
    return this.state.component
  }
}
```

However, when I mount it, it returns the following error:

```
Async.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.
```

Putting a console.log(this.state.component) in `Async`'s render function results in the following:

[image]

So what's going wrong here? It seems like I'm getting valid react components, so why is it throwing an error?

Comment: Should `import React, { Component } from 'react'` not be `import { React, Component } from 'react'`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox No, React is the default export of the 'react' package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're returning the component class, when you should actually be returning an element created *from* that class. They're not the same thing!

```
// Replace this:

render() {
    return this.state.component
}

// With this:

render() {
    return <this.state.component />
}

// Or this:

render() {
   return React.createElement(this.state.component)
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work because this.state.component isn't always a class. But `.then(component => this.setState({ component: React.createElement(component.About) }))` does solve it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you must wrap `this.state.component` within `{}` and a `<div>` and that what the error is about

You need to create an element out of the component

```js
class Async extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      component: React.createElement('div', {}, "loading")
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      this.state.component
    )
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<Async/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.2/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

```
class Async extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      component: React.createElement('div', {}, "loading")
    }
  }
componentDidMount() {
    System.import('../../about')
      .then(component => this.setState({ component: React.createElement(component.About) }))
      .catch(error => this.setState({ component: React.createElement('div', {}, error.message) }))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      this.state.component
    )
  }

}
```